# Не запускается Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2, после запуска в процессах на пару секунд появляется bds.exe и закрывается

Tags: запуск

Не запускается Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2, после запуска в процессах на пару секунд появляется bds.exe и закрывается. Помогает переустановка. Но через три месяца проблема появляется снова. Возможно, слетает просто какой-то параметр. Windows 10.

Comment: лицензия есть? или честно крякнутый?

Comment: Нет лицензии. Но он ее не требует. Просто не запускается.

Comment: купите лицензию и все должно работать. А если и после этого не будет - ну тогда напишите в официальный саппорт.